# Design 9 Divs HTML with the bottom-middle div flexible and the rest fixed

Tags: css, html

I want an html Page where it contains 9 Divs.

Div1   Div2   Div3

Div4   Div5   Div6

Div7   Div8   Div9

But I want it so that Div8 Is only flexible. It has a minimum width and height but as long as the window grows it can grow.
The rest of the divs are fixed size.
Div1, 4, 7 should be floating Left
Div3, 6, 9 should be floating right.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: What did you try? Where's your HTML/CSS code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question right, but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hXrSN/1/) is a fiddle describing your needs, ofcourse the `width` of the `divcontainer` elements can be variable, if you also adjust the div8 `max-width`. For resizing to viewport you can use percentages instead of pixels.